# Calculate WPF Webbrowser control Height while using Microsoft HTML Object Library

Tags: wpf, wpf-controls, webbrowser-control

Is there any way to find the height of the html file loaded in the Webbrowser control. I am using the Microsoft HTML Object Librray COM reference in project to access some document events . SO is any possibility is there to get Width and Height of the web pages loaded

I used below code with MHOL

```
         mshtml.HTMLDocument doc;
         doc = (mshtml.HTMLDocument)target.Document;
         mshtml.HTMLDocumentEvents2_Event iEvent;
         iEvent = (mshtml.HTMLDocumentEvents2_Event)doc;
         doc.body.style.overflow = "hidden"; //to make scrolbar invisible
```

Answer (score 0):

> Is there any way to find the height of the html file loaded in the
>   Webbrowser control

Try this:

```
dynamic document = webBrowser.Document;
var body = document.body;
var width = (int)body.offsetWidth;
var height = (int)body.offsetHeight;
```

If that doesn't give you what you're after, try `body.scrollWidth`/`body.scrollHeight`.